# dbunit tinyint improper value inserted into DataBase

Tags: junit, dbunit

I'm using JUnit with DBUnit and a MySQL database.

I have a field that is defined as a tinyint in the database. My xml file has a '5' for the field but when it gets inserted into the database, it is changed into a '1'.  Changing the Db definition to int allows the 5 to be inserted.

This is only a testing problem, but it's something that could skew results under the covers.

Is there a way to redefine the DbUnit mapping. Obviously, it is thinking that any tinyint is a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

Check the database type configuration, is it MySQL?  If needed, extend that class and change the behavior of specific field type handling.

Also, upgrade to the latest dbUnit version if needed.